# Use only class name without namespace in isinstance

Tags: python, python-2.6

This works in a script to recognise if a is of class myproject.aa.RefClass

```
isinstance(a, myproject.aa.RefClass)
```

But how could I do it so I do not have to specify the full namespace ? I would like to be able to type:

```
isinstance(a, RefClass)
```

How is this done in Python ?

EDIT: let me give more details.

In module aa.referencedatatable.py:

```
class ReferenceDataTable(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __call__(self, f):
        self._myfn = f
        return self

def referencedatatable_from_tag(tag):
    import definitions
    defn_lst = [definitions]
    for defn in defn_lst:
        referencedatatable_instance_lst = [getattr(defn, a) for a in dir(defn) if isinstance(getattr(defn, a), ReferenceDataTable)]
        for referencedatatable_instance in referencedatatable_instance_lst
            if referencedatatable_instance.name == tag
                return referencedatatable_instance
    raise("could not find")

def main()
    referencedata_from_tag("Example")
```

In module aa.definitions.py:

```
from aa.referencedatatable import ReferenceDataTable

@ReferenceDataTable("Example")
def EXAMPLE():
    raise NotImplementedError("not written")
```

For some reason calling the main from `aa.referencedatatable.py` will throw as it will not be able to recognise the instance of the class. But if I copy this main in another module it will work:

```
import aa.referencedatatable

a = aa.referencedatatable.referencedatatable_from_tag("Example")
print a
```

This second example works, for some reason calling this function inside the same module where the class is declared does not.

Comment: from myproject.aa import RefClass

Comment: Please do make your code example valid Python; you are missing a `:` on the `__init__`  and `__call__` lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'namespace' is just a *module* object, and so is the class. You can always assign the class to a different name:

```
RefClass = myproject.aa.RefClass
```

or better yet, import it directly into your own namespace:

```
from myproject.aa import RefClass
```

Either way, now you have a global name `RefClass` that references the class object, so you can do:

```
isinstance(a, RefClass)
```

Comment: The strange thing is that in the same module that I define my class I am unable to use isinstance without the full name

Comment: I am sure there is an explanation ... I put more details.

Comment: You may want to add a full traceback. I see your decorator returns `self`; so *calling* the decorated name will call the class *again*.

Comment: I will do this tomorrow

Comment: Also, your code example doesn't actually pass as Python; did you test with *just* the sample code to verify the problem still exists? Are you certain that you didn't use a decorator on the *class* itself? In that case the global name and the class object will *not* be the same, as the global name has been replaced by a different reference (whatever the class decorator returned).

Comment: @BlueTrin: Your sample, once fixed, works just fine, so you missed out a detail and mis-diagnosed the issue.

Comment: It is because I work currently in a system where I cannot copy paste any code (blocked by policy) so I am copying pasting. There is something weird, I still cannot get it to work in the main() of the declaration of the class. I guess it must be something with my local installation and not with the code.

Comment: @BlueTrin: verify in a debugger or with print statements with `id()` if you are actually dealing with the same object. You probably are missing a point where the class object and the global name `ReferenceDataTable` are no longer one and the same thing.